# Scammer stolel my crypto

Tags: ether

Unfortunately when I was sleeping and left my computer turned on, someone got into my pc and emptyed all my coins from all my soft wallets. I'm 100% sure the did not have my seeds and passwords as im long in crypto and never posted or enter them online.  I'm sure i must have hit a bad link somewhere and downloaded some malicious software that sat in my computer recording all my typing stroke. Lost a hell of a lot of money..any advice would be appreciated

Comment: Damn man, what a shame.

Answer (score 1):

If scammer has laundered money through tornado.cash, the chances of recovering funds is non existent, however I recommend you to inform your local authorities about this, I don't think they would look upon it seriously. After that you track down your address and possible transfers to the centralised exchanges, if they moved founds to CEX, you inform the exchange about possible stolen crypto along with the report of the local authority. Most possibly they would freeze the account of the scammer and recover funds.